# How can I embed an event listener into a conditional in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, event-handling

What is the best syntax to express: "If I click this, this will happen but if it is not clicked, then another action will occur"? I want to keep CSS, HTML and JS separate, if possible.

I am trying to write code for "If I click this button, then the video will appear & play. But when it is not clicked, the video is hidden".

```
button = document.getElementByIdId('button')
video = document.getElementById('video')

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
(action here)
}
```

Comment: So do you want it so that people need to hold the button to watch the video?

Comment: I want the video only to pop up and play when I click the button, otherwise I want it to stay hidden @Simp4Code

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener to your play button where it calls videoElem.play()

HTML:

```html
<video id='video'>
    <source src="your-video-source.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<button id='playVid'>Play</button>
```

Javascript:

```js
document.getElementById('playVid').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('video').play();
};
```

Comment: Thank you! But that does not answer my question. I know how to add an event listener to the video to play it. My struggle was doing this within a conditional to add an action to execute if NOT clicked too.